# New to Linux screen problems after login

Tags: login-screen

I am new to Linux just installed on Compaq with a hard driver that is completely clean. After I installed and booted up every thing works till I login. When I login the screen goes blury where I cant see anything. The Compaq model # SR5703wm and it has on board nvida driver.

Answer (score 0):

I have had serious problems with NVIDIA cards and Compaq machines running Linux. In my case, the default open source Ubuntu driver for NVIDIA (called Nouvea or something) was not compatable. If you can log in and open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and type xrandr -s 640x480 before it crashes on you, then you may be able to try running the 'additonal drivers' tool. If not...
Try this: The second you log in, press ctrl+alt+F1 which will bring you to tty1. Login with your username and password and try install the NVIDIA drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

and when that is done, type `sudo reboot` and hopefully the new driver will fix the problem. If you can't even get far enough to do that, than you'll have to boot into recovery with networking and install the NVIDIA driver. If you need help with that let me know. Hope this helps.